# How to eval (or echo) class variable in text in PHP

Tags: php, class, variables, echo, eval

I know it is possible to echo variables directly in text

```
$apples = 4;
echo "You have $apples apples."
```

How do it with class variable? This doesn't work.

```
class service {
    public $active;
}
$service["test"] = new service();
$service["test"]->active = true;

echo "Test service is: $service[test]->active";
```

I ask because I need to print class variable in eval (I use MyBB engine for forum).

`eval("\$site .= \"".$templates->get($template)."\";");`

Previously I've used `{$var}` and it worked but `{$var[sth]->sth}` doesn't.

Comment: `$service = new service(); $service->active = 'active'; echo $service->active;`

Comment: First instantiate your class! Then try and use it!!

Comment: And what has `$service["test"]` got to do with the price of cheeze? That suggests that you have an array of objects!! Do you??

Comment: If the answer is `eval()` **Then its 99% likely you are asking the wrong question**

Comment: I wrote in post that myBB needs it to print out page template

Comment: @RiggsFolly forgot to instantiate in example, I've already changed the post. And yes, I have array of objects.

Comment: Read the section on **Complex (curly) syntax** in the [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) documentation

Answer (score 0):

This works and there is no need for `eval()`

```
class service {
    public $active;
}
$service["test"] = new service();
$service["test"]->active = 99;

echo "Test service is: {$service['test']->active}";
```

Or

```
class service {
    public $active;
}
$service["test"] = new service();
$service["test"]->active = true;

echo "Test service is: " . $service['test']->active == true ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

Comment: Thank for fast reply. Okay it works with echo, but not with eval. I need eval because as I said, my forum uses it to print the page out. I have a page template (html) and page code (php). Template is printed out with this: `eval("\$site .= \"".$templates->get($template)."\";");` . If I have for example `$test = 4;` in code (php) then i write in template {$test} and its printed with template. I want to do same with class varriable but `{$service['test']->active}` doesnt work.